# Repeat calling of packages

Tags: perl

I am new to perl, this is normal to call the package in the other package?

main.pl

```
use MyPkg::Abc();  --> this is calling in Bcd() in Abc.pm
use MyPkg::Bcd();  --> if i don't call this, then the next line xxx() will be wrong..
xxx();
```

Abc.pm

```
use MyPkg::Bcd();
xxx();
```

Bcd.pm

```
sub xxx(){
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`use` tells perl to import stuff from another package. It's quite common to do this - one of the big advantages of `perl` is that there is a lot of work that has already been done, that you can reuse.

When you `use` a package, it loads it, and imports *some* of the subroutines in it into your current namespace. Occasionally it will do some other interesting things behind the scenes.

So yes - what you are literally doing is telling *your* program that the subroutine `xxx` is found in another module, and that you want to use that variant.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused by the parenthesis `()` in the `use` line.

```
use MyPkg::Abc();  # this is not calling MyPkg::Abc
use MyPkg::Bcd();  # neither is this
xxx();             # this calls sub xxx in your package
```

When you have a `use Foo::Bar` line in your program, Perl will go and find a file called `Bar.pm` in a folder `Foo` (so that's `Foo/Bar.pm` or `Foo\Bar.pm` on Windows) and load it. Usually that file will contain a `package Foo::Bar`. Now Perl knows about that package (also called namespace). Next it will call the `import` subroutine in the package `Foo::Bar`. This will make some of the subs in that package available in the *calling* package (i.e. your program). That process is called *importing*.

If you only want to import specific things, you can hand `import` a *list* of strings by putting that list after the `use` like this:

```
use List::Util ( 'min', 'max' );
use List::Util qw(min max); # same as above, just shorter
```

Now you get `min` and `max` in your program.

There are also modules that export (from their perspective, *import* from yours) things by default. If you don't want those to be in your namespace, you can give `use` an empty list.

```
use JOSN; # exports 'decode_json' and 'encode_json' by default
use JSON (); # doesn't export anything

my $json = JSON->new;
```

But if all you want is to load the subroutine `xxx` from `MyPkg::Bcd` and that packages exports it, then you should **not** have those `()` there. Or you must call the subroutine as `MyPkg::Bcd::xxx()`.